# @TimeLimit setting in Ola-Hallengren's IndexOptimize Running Much Longer Than The Value Set

Tags: index-tuning, ola-hallengren, index-maintenance

We start our indexing at 10:00 PM every evening and we want to allow it run until 4:30 AM, the next day.  Therefore, we set the @timelimit variable / parameter to 23400 seconds.  The issue is that the system continues to run well past the allotted time, by over 3607 seconds, or until I shut it down.

Thoughts on why it would not stop processing all commands, which is what the code is to promote via the variable?

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the [documentation](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) (and evident from the procedure source code), `TimeLimit` is used to

> Set the time, in seconds, **after** which no commands are executed.

(emphasis above is mine).

A command that started *before* the threshold will keep running until it completes.